# _layouts/Authenticate.aspx losing Query String Parameters in redirection in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

we are losing query strings when _layouts/Authenticate.aspx redirects to a application page after user authentication.

Example shown below

http Request is shown below

/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=http://ourwebsite.com/somepage.aspx?paramapp=testapp&paramdata=testdata

redirection happens fine, but all the query string expect the first gets truncated.

In the above the example paramdata gets truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue with out of the box Authenticate.aspx.

This is what we did. Suppose your URL looks like this

.../SomePage.aspx?Param1=value1&Param2=value2&Param3=value3&....

1. Created a Param object
   {
               "Param1" : "value1",
               "Param2" : "value2",
               "Param3" : "value3",
               ...
   }
2. Create a JSON string of the parameter. You can use the JSON.stringify() function. Encode this and send the parameter

JSON.stringify ({
                "Param1" : "value1",
                "Param2" : "value2",
                "Param3" : "value3"
})

**String** : "{"Param1":"value1","Param2":"value2","Param3":"value3"}"

**Encoded string**: %22%7B%22Param1%22%3A%22value1%22%2C%22Param2%22%3A%22value2%22%2C%22Param3%22%3A%22value3%22%7D%22

3. Pass this as a Param to your target page
   .../SomePage.aspx?Param=%22%7B%22Param1%22%3A%22value1%22%2C%22Param2%22%3A%22value2%22%2C%22Param3%22%3A%22value3%22%7D%22

This should pass through Authenticate.aspx and you will be able to retrieve the parameter. On page load, you can handle the object and get the individual parameter values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to confirm this but I have always seen the source information HTML encoded when being put in the URL. Perhaps this would be a good place to start. If that doesn't work then please post the code that you're using so we can see how you're doing this.

On a related note you're including the full address in the Source, you shouldn't really do this as it opens your users up to redirect attacks. A great explanation of this problem and how to resolve it is available from Troy Hunt [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-10.html).

Comment: Please find the below url. This is the exact scenario i have. I am facing this issue in sharepoint 2010. Authenticate.aspx is hosted under _layouts which is a out of the box page. I am not sure how to override the default functionality


http://forums.asp.net/t/1719377.aspx